# Como diminuir a luz azul em um website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Eu estou desenvolvendo um website, e gostaria de diminuir a luz azul (como modo noturno), muito porém, não encontrei meios de fazer isso.

Existe algum meio por CSS, JS ou alguma outra linguagem?

Comment: Na verdade, se entendi o que quer, é trocar a temperatura da cor... infelizmente não consegui achar nada que faça isso corretamente nas cores da página, então criei um filtro apenas para remover uma parte de azul.

Answer (score 13):

Um caminho extremamente simples e ao mesmo tempo objetivo é criar um elemento que cubra a *viewport* inteira com opacidade e *blend-mode* `multiply`. O `multiply`faz exatamente o que queremos, que é multiplicar as cores R G B arbitrariamente (no caso, atenuando o B especificamente):

```
mix-blend-mode: multiply;
```

E aqui definimos que a cor "cortada" será o azul (seria o caso de cortar um pouco do verde tambem):

```
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.2);
                        ^    ^   ^   ^
                        |    |   |   |
                        |    |   |   Opacidade (0.2 = 20%)
                        |    |   B = 0, 0% de azul (será controlado pela opacidade)
                        |   G = 255, 100% de verde
                        R = 255, 100% de vermelho
```

Poderiamos ter usado algo mais simples como `background-color:#ffffee`, sendo `ee` a intensidade do azul, mas isso daria problema no caso do `blend-mode` falhar nos navegadores antigos. A opacidade (rgba) foi escolhida apenas por uma questão de *fallback*. Num mundo "ideal" o `#ffff??` bastaria.

Finalmente, precisamos fazer com que nosso filtro não atrapalhe o usuário:

```
pointer-events: none;
```

isto faz com que nosso filtro fique sobre a página, mas que não afete o ponteiro do mouse, toques etc

### Demonstração:

```css
#menosazul {
  position: fixed; top:0; left:0; z-index:9999;
  height:100vh; width:100vw;
  pointer-events: none;
  background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0.2); /* o 0.2 é a opacidade */
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/ZU2cj.jpg" style="float:right;width:30vw;height:auto">
<p>
   Aqui é o conteúdo, seria sua página "normal".<br>
   Exagerei no 0.2 para que fique evidente o "pseudo-filtro", regule como desejado<br>
   <br>
   O pointer-events permite que o <button>botão</button>
   funcione sob o filtro<br>
</p>

<div id="menosazul"><!-- Aqui é o nosso "filtro" --></div>
```

Caso se trate de um navegador antigo e o *blend mode* falhe, as cores escuras são levemente afetadas, mas isto só é um problema sério se o filtro for muito exagerado. Note que de qualquer forma, o site ainda permanece usável.

### Ritmo Circadiano

A título de curiosidade, a motivação pela redução da luz azul tem relação com o Ritmo Circadiano (*circa dia*, em torno de um dia), que é o "relógio biológico" de quase todos os seres vivos.

Um dos componentes principais que regula os organismos é justamente a luz, em especial sua "temperatura" cromática. Cores mais avermelhadas/alaranjadas (quentes) são mais adequadas para o entardecer e anoitecer, enquanto cores mais "azuladas" (frias, e não restritas ao azul especificamente) são adequadas para o período da manhã.

Mais detalhes aqui:

> https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ritmo_circadiano

**Nota final**

Acho que se a preocupação é realmente com o azul, melhor seria simplesmente o *designer* do site reduzir os componentes azuis dos elementos na criação do CSS original, dispensando completamente a necessidade de qualquer elemento extra.

Poderia até trocar este CSS ou atualizar dinamicamente de acordo com o horário do PC do cliente (e torcer para o relógio estar correto). O filtro realmente poderia ser deixado apenas para situações onde o CSS convencional não fosse viável.

Answer (score 6):

Com um pouco de CSS e Javascript com jQuery eu fiz isso que segue. Clique no botão azul <kbd>Executar</kbd> lá em baixo para testar e veja os botões de <kbd>Acender a luz</kbd> e <kbd>Apagar a luz</kbd> que surgem.

```js
$("#apagar").click(function() {
    $("body").addClass("light-off");
});

$("#acender").click(function() {
    $("body").removeClass("light-off");
});
```

```css
body:not(.light-off) {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}

body.light-off {
    background-color: black;
    color: rgb(128, 128, 255);
}

#acender {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: black;
}

#apagar {
    background-color: rgb(128, 128, 255);
    color: white;
}

body:not(.light-off) #acender {
    display: none;
}

body.light-off #apagar {
    display: none;
}

#acender, #apagar {
    border: none;
    padding: 12px;
    border-style: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetuer adispiscing elit volupat.</p>
<button id="acender">Acender a luz</button>
<button id="apagar">Apagar a luz</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

A luz azul mencionada na pergunta é uma luz emitia pelos visores de tablets, celulares e monitores, e inclusive atrapalha porque ela é capaz de espantar o sono (sabe quando vc ta morrendo de sono e pega o celular e o sono sai vazado? A luz azul é a culpada!).

Hoje em dia as empresas estão cada vez mais preocupadas com a visão de seus usuários e estão começando a investir na luta contra a luz azul. (Na nova atualização do windows 10 existe uma função que pode reduzir a luz azul).

*Acredito que em um futuro próximo as linguagens de programação vão começar a se adaptar também a essa redução.*

Ok, sem mais lenga-lenga:

A luz azul pode ser reduzida com a exibição de cores mais quentes para o usuário, dessa forma é possível evitar a fadiga ocular deixando-o em um ambiente mais confortável. *(É claro que essa diminuição não é necessária todo o tempo, por isso as empresas gostam de chamar essa prática de **modo noturno**, uma vez que o usuário está cansado no fim do dia e pode usar essa função para ajuda-lo a dormir por exemplo).*

**AINDA** não existe nenhuma forma que realmente seja destinada para a diminuição de luz azul em práticas WEB. Entretanto pensando em um alternativa adequada veio as opções de filtros do CSS3

Os [filters](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_filter&preval=sepia(100%25)) são uma forte ferramenta capaz de manipular toda a coloração de um elemento na página.

Pensando nisso utilizarei o **filter: `sepia`**
Que naturalmente possuí cores visivelmente mais quentes e podem ser capazes de reduzir a luz azul emitida pelo dispositivo.

Veja:

```js
$("#cinquenta").click(function() {
    $("body").removeClass("sepia100");
    $("body").addClass("sepia50");
});

$("#cem").click(function() {
    $("body").removeClass("sepia50");
    $("body").addClass("sepia100");
});

$("#zero").click(function() {
    $("body").removeClass("sepia50");
    $("body").removeClass("sepia100");
});
```

```css
body.sepia50{
    filter: sepia(50%);
}

body.sepia100{
    filter: sepia(100%);
}

.jiu {
    background-color: rgb(128, 128, 255);
    color: white;
    border: none;
    padding: 12px;
    border-style: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Reduzir Luz Azul</h1>
<p>Você pode escolher a porcentagem de 0 a 100% de sepia.</p>
<button id="cem" class='jiu'>Sepia 100%</button>
<button id="cinquenta" class='jiu'>Sepia 50%</button>
<button id="zero" class='jiu'>Sepia 0%</button>

<br><br>
<img src='http://www.aprenderexcel.com.br//imagens/noticia/385/2901-1.jpg'>
```

Não é nem necessário dizer que se você não souber usar esse filtro de forma passiva, toda a sua página irá se tornar um grande pedaço de inutilidade né? (o botão **sepia 100%** é uma prova disso).

Lembrando que essa não é uma prática específica para remover a luz azul. Entretanto o filtro `sepia` naturalmente irá converter as cores da página para cores mais quentes e isso já pode ser um inicio adequado de redução da luz azul.

Comment: Gostei da resposta. Mas depois de clicar no "Sepia 100%", o "Sepia 0%" não funciona mais e eu tenho que clicar primeiro no "Sepia 50%" para depois clicar no "Sepia 0%". Já o contrário funciona.

Comment: No click o zero, você pôs duas vezes o `$("body").removeClass("sepia50");`. Uma delas era para ser o `$("body").removeClass("sepia100");`.

Comment: Sim sim, corrigido! Obrigado

Comment: Basicamente você acusou minha resposta de estar incorreta e fez o mesmo que eu fiz... Eu não troquei pro "modo escuro" apenas. Eu apliquei um filtro sob toda a página reduzindo todos os tons de azul, basta ver as imagens.

Comment: Olá Leon! Na verdade nós não fizemos a mesma coisa! O mix **hue** que você utilizou combina saturação com luminosidade, e não necessáriamente essa combinação será uma cor mais "quente"! Quando não possuimos controle total do cenário esse método utilizado as vezes pode até emitir mais luz azul! Já o sepia irá transformar tudo pra "quente" independete da cor.

Comment: Esta resposta merece uma recompensa.

Answer (score 4):

Depois de ler as outras respostas, resolvi implementar o meu filtro também. Ele remove 1/4 do componente azul de todas as cores.

Aproveitei e criei outro também, que escurece todos os componentes de cores em 3/4.

https://codepen.io/dudaskank/pen/NazoqQ

```js
$("#apply-filter").click(function() {
  $("body").removeClass("other-filter");
  $("body").addClass("blue-filter");
});
$("#remove-filter").click(function() {
  $("body").removeClass("blue-filter other-filter");
});
$("#other-filter").click(function() {
  $("body").removeClass("blue-filter");
  $("body").addClass("other-filter");
});
```

```css
body.blue-filter:before {
  pointer-events: none;
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 191);
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

body.other-filter:before {
  pointer-events: none;
  content: '';
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgb(64, 64, 64);
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}

#quadrado-azul {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Blue Light Filter</h1>
  <p>Blue light filter test</p>
  <p><button class="btn btn-outline-dark " id="apply-filter">Blue Filter</button>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-dark " id="remove-filter">No Filter</button>
    <button class="btn btn-outline-dark " id="other-filter">Other Filter</button>
  </p>
  <div id="quadrado-azul">Sample Blue Square</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Bacana! Mas vale lembrar que a luz azul não tem absolutamente nada haver com as cores azuis na página. Luz azul é apenas o nome dado, não faz relação com a cor azul e sim a luminosidade emitida por cores mais frias.

Answer (score 3):

Bom dia!

Fui dando umas fuçadas e acho que tenho uma coisa mais ou menos na linha que você está dizendo, se bem entendi o que você quer dizer com "diminuir a luz azul". Vê se é mais ou menos isso que você quer. Usei o `mix-blend-mode` para sobrepor a tela com um filtro diminuindo todos os tons azuis. Clique nos botões no início do exemplo.

```js
$("#apagar").click(function() {
  $("body").toggleClass("filter");
});

$("#acender").click(function() {
  $("body").removeClass("filter");
});
```

```css
body {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  -o-transition: 0.2s all ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s all ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s all ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.2s all ease-in-out;
}

img {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
}

#screen {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  -o-transition: 0.2s all ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s all ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s all ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.2s all ease-in-out;
}

body.filter {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 1);
}

body.filter #screen {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5);
  mix-blend-mode: hue;
}

body.filter p {
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="apagar" href="#">Apagar</button>
<button id="acender" href="#">Acender</button>

<br><br><br>

<img src="http://br.web.img2.acsta.net/pictures/17/03/23/12/22/099965.jpg" />

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur facilisis interdum pulvinar. Vestibulum luctus eget neque eget congue. Proin at mauris volutpat, volutpat ipsum at, sagittis urna. Fusce quis augue in risus rutrum malesuada id ac risus.
  Morbi consectetur tristique libero at feugiat. Morbi pretium justo volutpat, varius arcu a, ornare velit. Ut enim neque, fringilla interdum maximus venenatis, vulputate eu ligula. Vestibulum in varius nisl. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
  et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed dignissim, diam at feugiat maximus, risus tortor pharetra dolor, ut suscipit sem urna sit amet magna. Ut non nisi sed ipsum luctus facilisis. Suspendisse facilisis, velit sit amet sollicitudin aliquet,
  lacus purus laoreet nisl, vel finibus metus neque sed ex.</p>

<img src="http://www.istockphoto.com/resources/images/PhotoFTLP/img_75929395.jpg" />

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur facilisis interdum pulvinar. Vestibulum luctus eget neque eget congue. Proin at mauris volutpat, volutpat ipsum at, sagittis urna. Fusce quis augue in risus rutrum malesuada id ac risus.
  Morbi consectetur tristique libero at feugiat. Morbi pretium justo volutpat, varius arcu a, ornare velit. Ut enim neque, fringilla interdum maximus venenatis, vulputate eu ligula. Vestibulum in varius nisl. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
  et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed dignissim, diam at feugiat maximus, risus tortor pharetra dolor, ut suscipit sem urna sit amet magna. Ut non nisi sed ipsum luctus facilisis. Suspendisse facilisis, velit sit amet sollicitudin aliquet,
  lacus purus laoreet nisl, vel finibus metus neque sed ex.</p>

<img src="https://static-wix-blog-pt.wix.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/11-Lindas-Ideias-Para-Fotos-de-Beb%C3%AAs-02.jpg" />

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur facilisis interdum pulvinar. Vestibulum luctus eget neque eget congue. Proin at mauris volutpat, volutpat ipsum at, sagittis urna. Fusce quis augue in risus rutrum malesuada id ac risus.
  Morbi consectetur tristique libero at feugiat. Morbi pretium justo volutpat, varius arcu a, ornare velit. Ut enim neque, fringilla interdum maximus venenatis, vulputate eu ligula. Vestibulum in varius nisl. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus
  et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Sed dignissim, diam at feugiat maximus, risus tortor pharetra dolor, ut suscipit sem urna sit amet magna. Ut non nisi sed ipsum luctus facilisis. Suspendisse facilisis, velit sit amet sollicitudin aliquet,
  lacus purus laoreet nisl, vel finibus metus neque sed ex.</p>

<div id="screen"></div>
```

Comment: Quando eu clico no botão de Acender, ele dá uma piscada em amarelo bem rápida.

Comment: Quando você apaga a luz, as imagens ssofrem uma pequena alteração em suas cores. Isso é proposital?